# How to include multiple items in a tweepy status update

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, bots, tweepy

Hobbyist Pythoner here. I am using Tweepy to build a Twitter bot that responds to requests for links to research documents. I would like the response to look like this:

**Here you go @UserName: http:thelinkgoeshere.com**

In the code below the variable "link" refers to a URL looked up from a list.
The code I have been using is

```
api.update_status("Here you go: @" + tweet.user.screen_name, link)
```

But that isn't working. I can get it to tweet the first part through the user's ID or the link by itself, but not both. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
api.update_status("Here you go @{}: {}".format(tweet.user.screen_name, link))
```

Here's a link to help understand what `format` is doing: https://pyformat.info/.

I suspect that `api.update_status` only takes 1 argument, and you are giving it two.